# Поведение блоков в flex-контейнере

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Всем привет.
Есть блок, которому присвоен флекс (ширина 620 пикселей). В нем есть три блока, первые два с ширинами 50% и становятся в строку, а последний должен перейти на следующую сторку и встать посередине. Не получается у меня.
Что сделал:

```
&__visual {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    &__visual::nth-child(3) {
        flex-grow: 1;
```

Еще делал ширину третьего блока 100%, не хочет на середину вставать.
Сохраняет ширину 310 пикселей и прижимается к левому краю.

Как его передвинуть в середину?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 620px;
  height: 300px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.conteiner {
  margin: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="conteiner">
    <div class="content">Первый </div>
    <div class="content">Второй</div>
  </div>
  <div class="conteiner">

    <div class="content">Третий</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но этот вариант для планшетной верстки. Для мобильной блоки стоят друг над другом, а в верстке для компьютеров они выстаиваются в линию. Если первый и второй заключены в один блок, как ими манипулировать в дальнейшем?

Comment: Я тебе показал вариант, ты должен понять логику... Если понял, то уже в @media определи стили так как тебе надо...

Answer (score 0):

Решение пришло.

```
    <div class="page-footer__visual">
        <div class="page-footer__item">
        </div>
        <div class="page-footer__item">
        </div>
        <div class="page-footer__item">
        </div>
     </div>

&__item:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```